# Could not find a suitable constructor in com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, guice

I am new to Guice.
I want to create a server application with RESTful web services and Guice for DI. I followed the tutorial [here](http://randomizedsort.blogspot.de/2011/05/using-guice-ified-jersey-in-embedded.html), instead of a jetty I use a Tomcat6. But I cannot get it to run :(

I always get **Could not find a suitable constructor in com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer** on the application startup.

**Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class de.server.MyGuiceServletConfig
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer.class(GuiceContainer.java:108)
  at com.sun.jersey.guice.JerseyServletModule.webApp(JerseyServletModule.java:90)**

The GuiceContainer class has an constructor with an @Inject statement where it wants an Injector.

```
  @Inject
public GuiceContainer(Injector injector) {
    this.injector = injector;
}
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>de.server.MyGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My config class looks like this:

```
public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

public MyGuiceServletConfig() {

}

public class MyJerseyServletModule extends JerseyServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        // Must configure at least one JAX-RS resource or the
        // server will fail to start.
        bind(ITest.class).to(Test2.class);  
        bind(TestRestService.class);

        serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
    }
}

@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new MyJerseyServletModule());
}}
```

And last but not least the rest service:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestRestService {

private ITest test;

@Inject
public TestRestService(ITest t){
    this.test = t;
}

@GET
@Path("/getMe")
public String getMe() {
    return test.getName();
}


@GET
@Path("/getAll")
public Response getAll() {
    return Response.status(200).entity("sadsads").build();
}}
```

I don't know what I am missing. Hope you can tell me what I did wrong...

If you need any further information, just leave a comment and I'll add it.

Thx in advance,
TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

It sounds a little weird, but the problem is the following (I didn't mentioned it in my question, cause I never suggested that it could be the build process which causes the problems):

I defined a final name in my pom:

```
<build>
<finalName>mytest</finalName>
```

And this is exactly the problem. When I remove this line, everything works perfect...

Can someone tell me why this it is problematic to enter a final name when building a war?

Comment: I recently ran across this same issue. I think the solution was actually that you did a mvn clean after changing the finalName. I solved this problem with a mvn clean package after about 3 hours of looking at my configuration. I had run mvn war:war to copy my dependencies after adding the dependency to my pom. This got the server to start successfully but I believe there was some other problem that could only be resolved with a "mvn clean package".